# Android resource linking failed (Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0)

Tags: java, android

This is my error message, what can I do about this?

> Android resource linking failed Output: 
>   D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:10:
>   error: 'match_parent' is incompatible with attribute layout_weight
>   (attr) float. error: failed linking file resources.
>
> Command:
>   C:\Users\PALA.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b5935268f2c301ed81b7b1e07a1e89af\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>   link -I\
>           C:\Users\PALA\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
>           --manifest\
>           D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\resources\AndroidManifest.xml\
>           -o\
>           D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
>           -R\
>           @D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
>           --auto-add-overlay\
>           --java\
>           D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
>           --custom-package\
>           com.example.pala.hotwallpaper\
>           -0\
>           apk\
>           --preferred-density\
>           420dpi\
>           --output-text-symbols\
>           D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
>           --no-version-vectors Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: There seems to be an error in  D:\Furkan\HotWallpaper\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml, please share the xml from this file

Answer (score 1):

In your `activity_main` you somewhere assigned `match_parent` to `layout-weight` instead of `layout-width`.
So the reason for the error has been a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the the build, select the drop down on where it's showing you error at. It will give you an idea on the resource file that's causing the error.